# Server / Client based PC shutdown solution

Tags: windows-7, networking, shutdown

I need to shut down a bunch of Windows PCs in a local network from one central application, but I can't make use of the shutdown.exe remote command for some reasons.
However, I have admin rights on all the PCs in the network.

The best solution for me would be a client on the PCs that need to be shutdown.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Since you tagged as Windows 7, you could use Powershell:

`Stop-Computer –computer computerName –credential domain\administrator -force`

Using it on a list of computers:

`Stop-Computer -computer (Get-Content C:\temp\Desktops.txt) –credential domain\administrator -force`

[More info on Stop-Computer](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849839.aspx)